Error 500 Web API
tengo un problema al publicar mi web api hecha con .net 6 c#.
Al probarlo con swagger funciona perfectamente pero al publicarlo en el IIS para posterior consumirlo con Postman me devuelve un error 500.
using DealersWebAPI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;



namespace DealersWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class MainController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataContext db;
        public MainController(DataContext dataContext)
        {
            this.db = dataContext;
        }
        [HttpGet("Usuarios")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Usuarios>>> GetUsuarios()
        {
            var usuarios = await db.Usuarios.ToListAsync();

            return Ok(usuarios);
        }



Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Agregaste algun tipo de log para ver que metodo esta tirando el error?
